# Spring HttpSessionListener falls in loop

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, httpsession

I create a **HttpSessionListener** in my project. in this listener, I set something in session like below:

```
 public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    //some Business for access to subsiteId
    se.getSession().setAttribute("subsiteId", subsiteId);

    //set some atribute for Statistic Model
    iStatisticService.save(remoteIp, userAgent, page); 
 }
```

in my **GenericSave** (that my **StatisticService** extend it), I want to read subsiteId **Attribute** that I set already in **SessionListener**:

```
((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getAttribute("subsiteId")
```

But my app falls in loop. and come back to my Listener again! 
I guess me access to Session before it completely created.
any Idea?

Comment: Why do you let your service depend on the web, now your whole application is tied to the web layer? Just pass the id into the service method. Regarding the listener, the `RequestContextHolder` is only filled after the `DispatcherServlet` sees the request, if that is too late, register a `RequestContextListener` which does it as soon as the request is created, register it BEFORe your own listener. The listeners are executed in the order they are defined in, hence the ordering is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solve this problem by set attribute of Statistic Model in *sessionCreated* and save Statistic Model in *sessionDestroyed*:

```
@Override
public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    //set some atribute for Statistic Model
}

@Override
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    //save Statistic Model
}
```